# Switch on String 1.7

Tags: java

I imported a group project into Eclipse and got the following error:

> 'Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7'

Which is fine. I understand that switch on string was added in 1.7. When I quick fix my error to change my workspace or project compliance to 1.7, I end up with errors on pretty much every line of code.

Here's the error that is displayed at the top of the console:

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Driver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: You can use switch with a String variable/exression just since Java 1.7. Change your project settings to Java 1.7 and also add the Java 1.7 runtime. If you use Maven or other build tool, you have to set the Java version in POM.xml or its configuration file, not in project or global settings as well as in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are not just setting your workspace to java 1.7, but also that you have a java 1.7 JDK underneeth it.